# Distinguishing checkboxes with the same ID in different classes

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, dom

Hope you can help me regarding webscraping via VBA. In a webform I have to check and uncheck checkboxes using VBA. Now I run into the difficulty that some checkboxes have the same ID but reside in different classes.

Example:
Class "filter" has a checkbox with ID "start_date" and class "return_fields" has a checkbox with ID "start_date". When using .getElementByID("start_date") both checkboxes switch simultaneously.

But in this case I want to have the checkbox in class "filter" to be checked and the one in "return_fields" to be unchecked.

So I've attempted something like

```
.getElementsByClassName("filter")(0).getElementById("start_date").checked = True

.getElementsByClassName("return_fields")(0).getElementById("start_date").checked = False
```

Unfortunately this returns an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Here is the content of the element I get with .getElementByClassName("filter"):

```html
<legend>Date Mode</legend>
<div class="start_date required">
    <label for="active_date">Start Date</label>
    <input name="date_mode" class="radio" id="start_date" type="radio" checked="checked" value="start_date">
</div>
<div class="report_date required">
    <label for="report_date">Report Date</label>
    <input name="date_mode" class="radio" id="report_date" type="radio" value="report_date">
</div>
<div class="end_date required">
    <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
    <input name="date_mode" class="radio" id="end_date" type="radio" value="end_date">
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("filter")(0)` is giving you an element, so try `getElementsByClassName("filter")(0).checked=true` or looping through the resultant collection from the `getElementsByClassName("filter")` for the name start_date

Comment: or maybe try the `.getElementByID` without the (0)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the solution to the issue. I've copied in the result of the .getElementsByClassName statement. Within this element I need to point directly to one of the radio boxes.

Comment: Is the code at the end of your question the code you are trying to scrape? I don't see two identical IDs there. Also, using two IDs is invalid HTML; subsequent uses of an existing ID are ignored. Are you sure the markup you are scraping really has re-used IDs?

Comment: Yes. In another part of the webpage there's a different class name containing also a checkbox with ID and name "start_date". So I want to switch only one of them. But daisy chaining .getElementsByClassName("filter").getElementById("start_date") fails ("Object doesn't support this property or method")

Comment: Can you share the website? Are the classes in different Frames?

Comment: Classes are in the same frame. Sharing the (code of the) website is not possible as it is internal / confidential. In the example code above label, names etc. have been replaced by dummy tags. The code above is part of the class 'filter'. So I would like to know how to point to class 'filter' first and from there on point to ID 'start_date'.

Comment: You need to  include enough HTML to make this [MCVE]. I can't even see return_fields or filter in the above.